# Environmental Variables - Clearing Environment Variables WIN 7 PRO 32 BIT

Tags: laptop

I have a mess inside Environment Variables in system variables.

Each time Windows loads, the network and sharing icon keeps displaying the spinning icon for 1,2 even more minutes.... Everything is waiting for it to finish searching and discovering (this is what I think is happening) and finally Windows will load rest of system processes and come to life.

It took me a wile to find the reason (so I think): This Windows (hdd) was cloned many, many, many times by me for past 3 years and under all kinds of hardware combinations. Works flawless except rebooting.

Can somebody help me to remove unnecessarily luggage it is carrying around?

Comment: Will post the system variables as soon as I finish cloning the hdd witch im doing for this propose only, so please skip backup warning potential Help Dude!

Comment: Do you know where your Environment Variables are? If so okay. Just copy them and paste them into notepad. Every `;` you can press enter for a new line to get a good clean look at what you have going on. Then post them up after you've organized them.

Comment: I erased all just out of stupidity,  wow it works after reboot, no @@@@@@ hmmmm, this cant be.. o never mind back to Acronis True Image

Comment: thank you I`ll get on to it as soon..... unless I can edit system variables no access do to...

Comment: No disrespect and definitely this sounds just like I am disrespecting your heap by asking   TeamViewer 11 ?

Comment: O I do it all the time, and the dummis take days what I do in seconds, now Im a dummy lazy one

Comment: Do you know where your Environment Variables are? No clue, where are thy? is  there a text file to copy paste, cant get to system stings now

Comment: If you know how to use a terminal CMD? Prompt:> path ENTER, to view them. If you want to get them into a text file do this. On your desktop, on a clear spot, SHIFT + Right-Click, open command window here. Then at the prompt >echo path > myvars.txt

Comment: To get to them physically, Right Click on My Computer, then properties, then Advanced System Settings, Advanced Tab, Environment Variables. Here are your Environment Variables and System Variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this may help

user level path

```
C:\>echo %uvar%
HKCU\Environment
```

system/machine level path

```
C:\>echo %mvar%
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

C:\>
```

this link  has PATH and other environment variables

http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/09/default-environment-variable-values-of-windows-7-xp/

states that the default path in windows 7 is

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
```

that looks about right

I suppose You might be ok with a blank user path, but the machine path should have that.

So if you go to that key (easy with the sysinternals tool regjump

```
C:\blah>regjump "%mvar%"<ENTER>
```

Then you see the right hand side  name-data pairs (aka value-data pairs).

PATH is one of them.

There are others, see that link for other environment variables, they're at that same key.

Comment: When I echo %uvar% or %mvar% I don't see anything. You must have installed a program at some point and set these or the software set these variables?

Comment: @ejbytes I set them myself, I find them useful.  You might want to set them on your machine if you like the idea, but you don't need them. The point is the output from the echo, you see the 'path' to the environment variables.